# Как установить время жизни соединения в пуле?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

Здравствуйте. Использую пул соединений c3p0. Хочу, чтобы соединение жило как минимум минут 5. Пробовал все параметры типа MaxIdleTime, IdleConnectionTestPeriod. Все равно соединение закрывается где-то через минуту. Какой параметр все-таки нужно использовать?

```
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        сpds.setDriverClass( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );             
        cpds.setJdbcUrl( protocol+server+":"+port+"/"+table );
        cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(1);
        cpds.setAcquireRetryDelay(1);
        cpds.setUser(user);
        cpds.setInitialPoolSize(3);                    
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(3);
        cpds.setPassword(password); 
        cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(20*60);          
        cpds.setMaxIdleTime(20 * 60);                  
        cpds.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(5 * 60);   
        cpds.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(30 * 60);      
        conn=cpds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно, время ограничено на стороне сервера, вероятно, с помощью [*wait_timeout*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).

Comment: Да, точно, как-то совсем забил на сервер, пока возился с пулом. Спасибо.